# alternatives java jre vs jdk

Tags: java, linux, javac

I have a machine with several java installs. Below is snippet from alternatives java and javac:

JAVA:

1. /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_xx1/bin/java
2. /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_xx2-amd64/jre/bin/java
3. /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk/bin/java

JAVAC:

1. /usr/java/latest/bin/javac
2. /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_xx2-amd64/jre/bin/java
3. (3 is missing)

Machine setup:

- Why would they exist in different directories (/usr/java vs /usr/lib)? What is the linux/java reason for this, if any?
- Why /jre/bin/java rather than /bin/java in the second listing, and would the /bin/java be preferred?
- Why no javac for openjdk?

I am trying to ascertain if these alternatives were setup correctly because I need JDK for compiling code. Other machines show different alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

When there are several programs that respond to the same command in a system, the ‘alternatives‘ command let us set which will be the real program that will be executed when that command is called. This is very clear to see in the case of Java. There are several JDK implementations: OpenJDK, GNU, JDK from Oracle, etc. All these JDKs come with a ‘java‘ executable. Supposing we got several JDKs from different vendors installed, which will be the one executed in our system when the ‘java‘ program runs

for more explanation check this blog.
https://blogs.igalia.com/dpino/2011/10/13/configuring-different-jdks-with-alternatives/

Comment: So command sudo alternatives --install was used and the above was configured manually? Any reason why amd64/jre/bin/java vs amd64/bin/java ?